# Passing json as command line argument in Unix

Tags: c++, c, json, unix, getopt

I am trying to pass a json string as command line argument to my c++ application in a Unix environment.

```
.\SampleApp -j {\"speed\":\"15\",\"rpm\":\"100\",\"loc\":[\"-83.11\",\"42.11\"]}
```

I'm using getopt() function in my sample app to parse the arguments. At the output I am receiving only speed:15. But when I run the application as

```
.\SampleApp -j \"speed\":\"15\",\"rpm\":\"100\",\"loc\":[\"-83.11\",\"42.11\"]
```

it works. My question is how do I pass the json string with curly braces properly to the application. 
I tried using escape sequence, `\{`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, it easier to use single quote when the text has double quotes

```
./SampleApp -j '{"speed":"15","rpm":"100","loc":["-83.11","42.11"]}'
```

Or over multiple lines for readability:

```
./SampleApp -j '
{
    "speed":"15",
    "rpm":"100",
    "loc":["-83.11","42.11"]
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by just passing the argument inside **"**. Also, it's <kbd>./</kbd>, not <kbd>.\</kbd>.

```
./SampleApp -j "{\"speed\":\"15\",\"rpm\":\"100\",\"loc\":[\"-83.11\",\"42.11\"]}"
```